# What are alternatives to the Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-app-store

I've already published a few apps for the Mac App Store and am just wondering if there are alternatives to the Mac App Store? I would prefer not to self-host the applications (because I know almost nothing about servers) and would like a system like the Mac App Store where I just upload and forget about the distribution infrastructure.

Any easy and creative distribution methods would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the App Store suits your needs. Any reason for your desire for alternate distribution methods, or are you just exploring?

Comment: I don't want to be solely dependent on the rules of Apple. I would like to use other distribution methods so that I can add features not approved by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

[Bodega](http://appbodega.com/Developers.php) looks very nice. (I’ve never used it, though, neither as a user nor as a developer)

Comment: I've looked into Bodega but, it's just a front end for the user. App hosting is still left up to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

[Setapp](https://setapp.com) is a great alternative. It's a subscription service for Mac apps. Users pay per month and they get a great list of apps.

Besides that, they help you with marketing so you can focus more on development. You can apply your app in https://setapp.com/developers.

[image]